# Conversation Scope in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, cdi, myfaces, codi

I am trying to implement conversation scope in backing bean of JSF for our application. At first, I am trying to use MyFaces Orchestra. It seems to work well. However, I am concerning the case when the application deployed in cluster environment and during session replication. Then, I am thinking if MyFaces CODI and OpenWebBeans are better choice or not.

I have two questions to ask:

**(1) MyFaces Orchestra claims that it does not support distributed sessions. Does it means that it does not work well in cluster environment?**

**(2) Does MyFaces CODI have any issues when deployed in cluster environment?  I cannot found any information about this in its document.**

Comment: those questions are pretty framework specific and might be better placed in a relevant MyFaces forum

Answer (score 0):

If your server supports clustering of CDI session scoped beans, you can also cluster MyFaces CODI conversations.

Comment: Thanks Dar Whi, do you know if Weblogic 10.3.4 support clustering of CDI session scoped beans?